# How to set an empty drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I'm dealing with bugs in the Facebook SDK and so to remove the bugs I'll need to set a drawable to nothing not NULL just nothing or empty space or something. How can I do that programmatically?

```
Drawable=...
```

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can use a transparent `ColorDrawable`:

```
Drawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

That's a `Drawable` that represents the transparent color and doesn't have an intrinsic size.

Comment: So if you try to get the intrinsic width, what will it return?

Comment: i'd say -1, according to the source.

Comment: Thanks man. I used your code and it worked. I think it returned 0 or something. Doesn't matter it worked.

Comment: The most straightforward solution.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Empty Drawable with width and height can be made using a **transparent ColorDrawable** and the function **setBounds(Rect)**

```
 int left=0,top=0,right=32,bottom=32;
 Drawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 transparentDrawable.setBounds(left,top,right,bottom);
```

If you want an empty drawable of dimensions same as another drawable(say d):

```
 Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_drawable);
 Drawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 transparentDrawable.setBounds(new Rect(0, 0, d.getMinimumWidth(), d.getMinimumHeight()));
```

Comment: What would be the XML equivalent? No ColorDrawable at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource